# How to change existing forms layout to use simple_form layout in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I currently found [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) gem for rails application. I currently join the rails project and added this to existing project. 
After installation it creates form for new migrations with **simple_form**. I want to migrate all existing forms to use simple_form.

How can I accomplish existing non simple_form layout forms  to use *simple_form* layout.

Is there any way to generate forms using console or script to make simple_form layout?

Comment: I think that `simple_form_for` still has access to the same methods as `form_for`. Try replacing a `form_for` in your app with a `simple_form_for`. If it still works, it means that `simple_form_for` can either use its own DSL (methods, options, etc) OR use the good old syntax of `form_for` (which would mean no need for extra coding for you!)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there is a generator that can translate all your other forms in to the simple_form layout for you.

If the forms you have now currently work, I would say there is no need to change them. The point of the gem is to make it easier to create new forms. Use simple_form going forward and leave the ones that work. In the future if any form breaks, rewrite it in the simple_form DSL.